# aws s3api put-object command does not work as expected

Tags: amazon-s3

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html

the line to put a file into bucket using aws s3api is

```
   aws s3api put-object --bucket text-content --key dir-1/my_images.tar.bz2 --body my_images.tar.bz2
```

I used the example as above to put my file into bucket:

```
   $ aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket-witha3api2 --key 
   test/TestDataforAWSs3api.txt --body TestDataforAWSs3api.txt

   {
     "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\""
   }
```

After I list the bucket I see the following:

```
   aws s3 ls s3://mybucket-witha3api2/test

                       PRE test/
```

I am not sure where is the file TestDataforAWSs3api.txt and what is PRE? Could you explain please what is wrong with my CL?

Thank you.

Comment: PRE is a common prefix.  Try `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket-witha3api2/test/` (add a trailing slash).

Comment: Think of a common prefix as being a folder name. Sort of.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trailing slash or else what you're doing is a check on the existence of an object with the name `test` in the bucket `mybucket-witha3api2`. The file `TestDataforAWSs3api.txt` exists but you are not checking using the correct prefix noted as `PRE`. To check for the existence of your file you can list the objects with the `test` prefix like this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket-witha3api2/test/
```

or you can explicitly check for the file itself

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket-witha3api2/test/TestDataforAWSs3api.txt
```